# Seforim written by Dutch Jewry

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

In [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/126625/27180), a sefer called מנהגי אמשטרדם - Minhagei Amsterdam is introduced. I have taken a quick look into that sefer (since I'm from the Netherlands) and in the hakdamah (introduction from the author), a sefer called [בנין אריאל - Binyan Ariel](https://hebrewbooks.org/19443) is cited.

The author of Binyan Ariel is [Rabbi Shaul of Amsterdam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Lowenstam) [(Minhagei Amsterdam, hakdamah, p. 7)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/147488/p/8/t/0.103493794509312621234/fs/HStcUWCPC6YBAjROQaiGNxOR6Mi9kLCNGgIq0lplEgMK/start/0/end/13/c):

> בית המדרש בנין אריאל מצא את שרשיו בבית המדרש עץ חיים שנוסד בשנת הח"ק המייסד היה הגאון רבי אריה לייב רבה של אמשטרדס חתן הגאון בעל חכם צבי מטרות בית המדרש היו להגיש לציבור הלומדים אפשרות לעסוק בלימוד המודרך ע"י מורים מיוחדים לכך ולסייע לתלמידים חסרי אמצעים בנו של הגאון רבי אריה לייב זצ"ל היה הגאון הנודע רבי שאול אמשטרדם מחבר הספר בנין אריאל אשר מילא את מקומו של אביו ועשה רבות לקידומו של בית המדרש ביוזמתו נוסד בשנת התק"כ אירגון הנקרא סעדת בחורים אשר מטרותיו היו למנות מורים ולעזור לתלמידים במילוי הצרכים הגשמיים שלהם

I was wondering if there are any other seforim, written by Dutch Rabbi's? I am looking on seforim with explanations on Torah.

Any tips/recommendations on seforim that are available online? (HebrewBooks or Otzar HaChochmah)?

Comment: Should be בִּנְיָן no? Benin sounds like a country in Africa.

Comment: avraham pimental

Comment: [רבנים הולנדים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D)

Comment: Rabbi Menashe Ben Yisrael was part of the Portuguese community in Amsterdam in the 17th century. He has some works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menasseh_Ben_Israel

Comment: The חכם צבי served as rov inAmsterdam and wrote seforim. Whether he wrote thoem whilst in Holland is beyoond me?

Comment: @terryg Thanks, but the Chacham Tzvi was not Dutch IIRC.

Comment: Maybe עמודי בית יהודה would qualify (although I'm not sure if the author was a rabbi, he received approbations from both the Ashkenazi and Sefardi Chief Rabbis of Amsterdam): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66516/

Comment: @Fred Yes, that is one of the ones I was looking for. Do you know if he wrote seforim on the parasha?

Comment: @Shmuel Not that I know of, although there are parsha tidbits in that sefer, e.g.: "הבט נא וראה לזרע יעקב שבטי ישורון כמה מהרעות קרה אותם, ומה שחשבו לתכלית הרעות המה היה סיבות הטובות. לעבד נמכר יוסף הצדיק מאחיו. המה חשבו לרעה והאלוקים חשבה לטובה ולמחיה שלחו ה' להחיות עם רב כידוע מתורתינו הקדושה.  וכן להיפך: נשיאת יוסף וממשלתו, היא הייתה סיבה לעבדותם ושפלותם, והעבדות ההיא הייתה סיבה אל הניסים והפורקן והישועות כידוע. אם כן מהאומה הזאת תבחן שהרעות היו סיבות טובות וכי הרעות והטובות על קו אחד יעמדו והמה מקושרים בקשר השגחתו יתברך.  וכמה נעימים דברי חז"ל באמרם : כשם שמברכין על הטובה כך מברכין כו'."

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_ben_Mordecai_Zacuto

Comment: The Chacham Tzvi was also the rav of Amsterdam. The Ramchal wrote Mesilas Yesharim in Amsterdam

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/59100

Comment: @wfb thank you. Nice addition. Raphael Evers is a famous Rabbi here. Never known that he had written seforim though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this classic called [Sefer Eit Keitz](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42127&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=) written by Rabbi Yitchok Chaim HaKohen from Amsterdam. Again, heavily sourced and worth learning with the footnotes. The book was published in 5470 and deals with the subject of the redemption as found throughout the Torah.